# Ayuda! Error al guardar Formulario

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, windows-forms, postgresql

Quiero guardar un formulario pero al guardarlo me manda este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el Codigo que tengo. Me podrian decir en donde esta el error

```html
                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("registrar_producto", conexion);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_identificacion", Convert.ToInt32(identificacion_cliente.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_nit", Convert.ToInt32(nit_proveedor.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_fecha", Convert.ToDateTime(fecha.Text));
                codigo.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                for (int i=0; i < tblaproductos.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_descripcion", Convert.ToString(tblaproductos.Rows[0].Cells["producto"].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_cantidad", Convert.ToInt32(tblaproductos.Rows[1].Cells["cantidad"].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_precio", Convert.ToInt32(tblaproductos.Rows[2].Cells["precio"].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_subtotal", Convert.ToInt32(tblaproductos.Rows[3].Cells["subtotal"].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_total", Convert.ToInt32(tblaproductos.Rows[4].Cells["total"].Value));
                }
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

PD: Al agregar datos directo en el SP si guarda

Este es el sp que utilizo para insertar los datos registrar_productos

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.registrar_producto(
p_fecha timestamp without time zone, p_descripcion character varying,
    p_cantidad integer,  p_precio integer,
    p_subtotal integer,
    p_total integer,
    p_identificacion integer,
    p_nit integer)
    RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE p_codigo int;
BEGIN

INSERT INTO producto(fecha,descripcion,cantidad,precio,subtotal,total,identificacion,nit) VALUES (p_fecha,p_descripcion,p_cantidad,p_precio,p_subtotal,p_total,p_identificacion,p_nit) RETURNING codigo INTO p_codigo;
RETURN p_codigo;
```

Answer (score 0):

En la primera parte del código asocias el procedimiento almacenado registrar_producto al command cmd y añades parámetros @p_identificacion, @p_nit y @p_fecha

Asegúrate de que existe ese procedimiento con esos parámetros en BBDD.

Lo que me parece llamativo es que justo después del cmd.ExecuteScalar(), recorres un bucle en el que a la misma variable command le añades más parámetros de los que ya tenía.

O bien la segunda parte dentro del bucle debía apuntar a un procedimiento almacenado distinto, o bien sobra el primer cmd.ExecuteScalar()

Sería bueno saber si lo que falla es el primer 
 codigo.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

..o el segundo
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Espero haber ayudado en algo. Si persiste el problema por favor comparte el código de "registrar_producto"

Saludos

EDIT => 
cuando llamas a ExecuteScalar aun no has definido todos los parámetros que necesita la función registrar_producto.

Además el resto de parámetros los defines dentro de un bucle, lo cual te va a dar nuevos problemas.

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("registrar_producto", conexion);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Clear();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_identificacion", Convert.ToInt32(identificacion_cliente.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_nit", Convert.ToInt32(nit_proveedor.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_fecha", Convert.ToDateTime(fecha.Text));

//Aquí los parámetros aun no se han definido !
//codigo.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_descripcion", Convert.ToString(tblaproductos.Rows[0].Cells["producto"].Value));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_cantidad", Convert.ToInt32(tblaproductos.Rows[1].Cells["cantidad"].Value));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_precio", Convert.ToInt32(tblaproductos.Rows[2].Cells["precio"].Value));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_subtotal", Convert.ToInt32(tblaproductos.Rows[3].Cells["subtotal"].Value));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_total", Convert.ToInt32(tblaproductos.Rows[4].Cells["total"].Value));

//No hay contexto para tblaproductos así que no se muy bien para que lo usas

//for (int i=0; i<tblaproductos.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
//{
//    codigo.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
//}

codigo.Text = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Hola...el codigo falla en **codigo.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();**  y ya edite mi pregunta

Comment: te edito la respuesta también amigo.  Suerte espero que te ayude

Comment: Enigma me aparece otro error me dice **el indice esta fuera del intervalo.Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la coleccion**

Comment: Casi seguro e problema está en tblaproductos.Rows[x].Cells["x"]. Pon el método completo por favor, o bien tu mismo revisa el uso que haces de tblaproductos